# Ordered Set example. Why is partially ordered?

Tags: relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations

I am studying these concepts of order for the first time, and I am having a certain difficulty:

I define an Order relation in $A=\mathbb{R_{+}^{2}}$ as :  $x,y \in A$, $x\geq y \iff x_{1} \geq y_{1}$ and $x_{2} \geq y_{2}$

Its well known that this relation is partially ordered: it is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. But is not totally ordered.

Here is where begins my doubts: **I dont understand why it is transitive and reflexive?**

I belive if I choose a counter-example, I can show that it is not transitive and relexive, right?:

If I choose $x=(1,3)$ and $y=(\frac{1}{2},4)$ and $y=(\frac{1}{3},5)$ :

- Does it reflexive? Yes. Because $x \geq  x$, because $x_{1} \geq x_{1}$ and $x_{2} \geq x_{2}$
- Does it transitive? How can I show that, with x, y and z, transitive condition holds? Also for the Antisymmetric condition?

What do I missing? Any help guys?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

For transitivity, suppose $x\le y$ and $y\le z$. By definition, that means that $x_1\le y_1$, $x_2\le y_2$ and $y_1\le z_1$ and $y_2\le z_2$. Therefore, by transitivity of the order in $\mathbb{R}$, you have $x_1\le z_1$ and $x_2\le z_2$. But that means, by definition, that $x\le z$.

For antisymmetry, if you have $x\le y$ and $y\le x$ that means $x_1\le y_1\le x_1$ and $x_2\le y_2\le x_2$, which imply (by antisymmetry of the order in $\mathbb{R}$) $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$, that is, $x=y$.

Comment: thanks! But whats is the problem whith my counter examples?

Comment: @Laura I suppose in you tentative of counter-example, $z=(1/3,5)$, that is, $z$ and not $y$. Then you have $x_1>y_1>z_1$ but $x_2<y_2<z_2$. That means that you don't have either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq z$ (and the same with $z$), so you don't have the hypothesis to build a conuter-example

Comment: Your points are not comparable. Neither does $x\le y$ or $y\le x$. Remember that your order is only a partial order, not a total order.

Comment: Yes @GReyes I understand that it not total order. My question is, why it is a partiall order? Because I can use my counter example to prove that is not Total. But with my counter example I can not show that is trnasitive, for example.

Comment: @Laura You can't prove that the relation is transitive with that example or any other one. It is a matter of quantifiers (but you could prove that it isn't, if it weren't, by a counter-example). The simple proof of transitivity (and of anti-symmetry) is as GReyes put in the answer.

Comment: A counterexample would be finding $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x\le y$, $y\le z$ BUT $x$ is not $\le z$. In your example, it is not true that either $x\le y$ or $y\le z$, so whatever the relation between $x$ and $z$, it would not be a counterexample.

Comment: @amrsa many many thanks! Now I understand. It is not about proving!